# Can't Fetching simple JSON array in spinner

Tags: android, json

My json array

```
["a","b","c","d"]
```

I have used the following code to get json data,,,,
I can get one data from json array by using `textview.setText(jr.get(i));`
Then I have tried to fetch total array in spinner.By using log i have checked for my list size,it shows 4,So what is the error here..
It shows

```
03-07 00:38:11.468: E/(1184): List(size) 4
03-07 00:38:11.558: E/AndroidRuntime(1184): java.lang.NullPointerException
```

My java

```
protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            try {
                 JSONArray jr = new JSONArray(result);
                 for(int i=0;i<jr.length();i++)
                 {
                     list.add("" +jr.get(i));    
                 } 
                } catch (JSONException e1) 
                {   
                e1.printStackTrace(); 
                }
                Log.e("", "List(size) " + list.size());
                if(list!=null)
                {

                adapter=new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, list);
                adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
                spin.setAdapter(adapter); 
                }
    }
```

Comment: are you sure you are initializing spin instance of Spinner ?

Comment: At which line are you getting NPE? Also must be sure that Spinner object not be null.

Comment: Prosper u r right,,,I didnt initialized.
I thought my postexecute oly wrong,,,,

Comment: Mostly what is the reason for null pointer exception,,,Because am always getting this kind of error.

Comment: which kind of error? Show that line at where you r getting null pointer exception.

Comment: @piyush in my code the problem is due to that i didnt initialized spinner item,,,,This is the reason for NPE,,